# Android Exoplayer : Get currentTime for a live stream

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x, live-video

How do you get the current time for a live video(rtmp) when using Exoplayer? 
I tried

```
player.getCurrentPosition()
```

but the values start from 0 and not the actual time of the live stream. Is it possible to get the actual video time?

Comment: can you try this getCurrentTimeline().  http://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/Player.html#getCurrentTimeline--

Comment: @Mohsinmithawala Nope I have tried that. I don't get the required data from that field i.e the current live video time.

Comment: this is issue on github repository please check below link:
https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/2289

Answer (score 1):

In this case, I implement with subtraction between date now with user start date playing like this. **dateStartPlaying** is initialized when we want to play some content / change the content.

```
private long getCurrentTimeLiveStreaming(){
    return new Date().getTime() - dateStartPlaying.getTime();
}
```